# Blink animation on TextView with text changing simultaneously

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-animation, handler

I have an array of Strings and want to display one String at a time with blink animation (after a blink another String in textView). I did the animation part with the  code below:

On OnCreate:

```
    TextView subTitle=findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
 Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            anim.setDuration(2500); 
            anim.setStartOffset(0);
            anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            subTitle.startAnimation(anim);
```

and changing the textview text with this:

```
  Handler h = new Handler();
        int delay = 2500;
        Runnable runnable;
    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            h.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    selected = subTtls[new Random().nextInt(subTtls.length)];
                    subTitle.setText(selected);
                    h.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
                }
            }, delay);
            super.onResume();
        }
```

But the text of textView does not change simultaneously with blink. Is there a single way I can do this?

Comment: can you post your code where you're applying the animation

Comment: @ManojPerumarath please refer to the edited code.

Comment: try this :  subTitle.startAnimation(anim);

Comment: @SofianeMajdoub please read the whole question and code first.

Comment: i readed both of them and you haven't applied the animation for your textview.

Comment: @SofianeMajdoub last line of first block of code. haven't you seen that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below...

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
//if set animation count to once
selected = subTtls[new Random().nextInt(subTtls.length)];
                    subTitle.setText(selected);
anim.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
// Or if set repeat count to infinite
selected = subTtls[new Random().nextInt(subTtls.length)];
                    subTitle.setText(selected);
    }
});
```

Modify as you want...

Comment: This is right answer, You can explain why handler will not work as expected to understand better.